# Hotkey for moving to interface's (DataSource) implementation method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, resharper, mvvm-light

I'm using `MVVMLight` and `IOC datasource approach`. The thing is that when i need to jump to method implementation (like `dataService.GetData()`), i'm pressing `F12`, and jumping to interface itself.

The question is: are there any tricks or hotkeys to select implementation class (designtime or realtime) and jump fast to method? Maybe in Resharper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the cursor on `GetData`, do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>. This is the default keybinding in the VS scheme for `ReSharper | Navigate | Derived Symbols`. It can also be found on the `Navigate To` context menu, accessed with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.